# Ignore "$" at the beginning of the command in Bash

Tags: bash

On many websites, "$" is written at the beginning when introducing the Linux command.
But of course, this will result in a "$: command not found" error.

To avoid this it is necessary to delete or replace "$" every time, but it is troublesome.

So, if the beginning of the input command is "$", I think that it would be good if I could ignore "$", is it possible?

Comment: I don't think you can, but even if you could, I wouldn't recommend that. The best way to learn is to *actually type* the commands instead of copy-paste them.

Comment: Or, simply don't copy the `$`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either. Many things in bash can start with a `$`. For example, I have a command I frequently use on the startup of my VM: `$(< Documents/shared_folder )` for mounting a shared folder with the host system. It's just the `mount` command offloaded in a file. However, it requires the `$` at the front of the command to parse the file as a bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need this, you can create a file in a directory that is in your $PATH. The file will be named `$` and will contain

```
#!/bin/bash
exec "$@"
```

Make it executable, then you can do

```
$ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ $ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ $ $ echo foo bar
foo bar
$ $ $ $ echo foo bar
foo bar
```

Note that this does not affect variable expansion in any way. It only interprets a standalone `$` as the first word in the command line as a valid command.

---

I just noticed a problem with this: It works for calling commands, but not for shell-specific constructs:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo $foo
bar
$ $ foo=qux
/home/jackman/bin/$: line 2: exec: foo=qux: not found
```

and

```
$ { echo hello; }
hello
$ $ { echo hello; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

---

In summary, everyone else is right: use your mouse better.

Comment: My first thought was to create a function, but `function $ { "$@"; }` gives ``bash: `$': not a valid identifier``

Comment: I do not disagree with you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible for you to ignore the command prompt, when copying commands from web sites. Use the shift and arrow keys to ignore the prompt. This will also help you to ignore the use of the `#` sign, which is used to indicate commands, which need administrative privileges.